# bash script for cdo command to run it on different files

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am new in UNIX and I want to apply the CDO (Climate Data Operator) "remapbil" command in order to transform the grid (from a projection to geographical coordinate system). it works perfectly fine for 1 single file with the following command:

```
cdo remapbil,target.grd hurs_EUR-11_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_rcp26_r3i1p1_DMI-HIRHAM5_v1_day_20360101-20401231.nc hurs_36_40_bil.nc
```

But I have to do it for a lot of different files. For this reason, I have tried to write the following bash shell that will allow me to run the remapbil command for all file i have in my directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.nc;
do
echo $i
for file in "ls *.nc"; do
cdo remapbil,target.grd tas_EUR-11_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_rcp45_r3i1p1_DMI-HIRHAM5_v1_day_20210101-20251231.nc > tas_$i_bil.nc
done
done
```

But i always get the following Error:

```
cdo remapbil (Abort): Too few streams specified! Operator needs 1 input and 1 output streams.
```

Can probably someone help me, that would be great

Comment: Doesn't your i and file variables represent the same thing? It seems to me that you are unnecessarily nesting loops.

Answer (score 0):

The `for file in "ls *.nc"; do . . . ; done` will run the command once, with literal argument `ls *.nc` - as you can confirm as follows:

```
$ ls *.nc
bar.nc  foo.nc
$ for file in "ls *.nc"; do echo "$file" ; done
ls *.nc
```

You presumably intended a *command substitution* using backticks in place of double quotes *but that would be a bad idea*<sup>1</sup> and is unnecessary since you are already looping over the files using a (safe if quoted) shell glob. So:

```
for i in *.nc;
do
echo $i
cdo remapbil,target.grd  "$i" > "tas_${i}_bil.nc"
done
```

If you want to remove and replace the extension in the output file, you can change `"tas_${i}_bil.nc"` to `"tas_${i%.nc}_bil.nc"`

---

1. [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: thanks for your respond, but the command which has to executed must have to format like: (cdo remapbil,>targetgrid> <input> <output>) otherwise it doesn´t work. Therefor i have different inputfiles and one fixed targetgrid in a different format, so the bash should do it for every single file in the directory. But unfortunately it doesn´t

Comment: @C.Utz apologies - see edit

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfektly well for my problem.